# How to get CStarRating in CgridView - Yii

Tags: yii

How can I get each row a starRating. I would like to show the current stars and if the user wants to update the stars, he can click to update it.

My error is undefined $data.

gridview:

```
...
'columns'=>
...
array (
    'name' => 'star',
    'type' => 'raw',
    'value'=>'$this->grid->controller->widget("CStarRating",
                array("starCount"=>"5",
                "minRating"=>"1",
                "maxRating"=>"5",
                "ratingStepSize"=>"1",
                "allowEmpty"=>false,
                "name"=>"rating".$data->id,
                "callback"=>"function(){
                url = "controller/action";
            jQuery.getJSON(url, {id: "$data->id", val: $(this).val()},
                        function() {
                           if (data.status !== "success"){
                                    alert("error");
                 }});}",),true)',                           
),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
'value'=> function($data){
         $controller = Yii::app()->getController();
         return $controller->widget("CStarRating",
            array("starCount"=>"5",
            "minRating"=>"1",
            "maxRating"=>"5",
            "ratingStepSize"=>"1",
            "allowEmpty"=>false,
            "name"=>"rating".$data->id,
            "callback"=>'function(){
            url = "controller/action";
        jQuery.getJSON(url, {id: "'.$data->id.'", val: $(this).val()},
                    function() {
                       if (data.status !== "success"){
                                alert("error");
             }});}',),true);
         },
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
array (
'name' => 'star',
'type' => 'raw',
'value'=>'$this->grid->controller->widget("CStarRating",
            array("starCount"=>"5",
            "minRating"=>"1",
            "maxRating"=>"5",
            "ratingStepSize"=>"1",
            "allowEmpty"=>false,
            "name"=>"rating".$data->id,
            "callback"=>"function(){
            url = "controller/action";
        jQuery.getJSON(url, {id: \'.$data->id.\', val: $(this).val()},
                    function() {
                       if (data.status !== "success"){
                                alert("error");
             }});}",),true)',                           
),
```

Comment: the stars don't show up if i add callback... Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: i mean in your application where this error happens?

Comment: The quotes in the callback have been escaped wrong. All the quotes in the callback should be escaped.

Answer (score -1):

Looks to me you have one quotation too many. Change ;

```
'value'=>'$this->grid->controller->widget("CStarRating",
```

to

```
'value'=>$this->grid->controller->widget("CStarRating",
```